# How to delete a reaction with a raw event

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Good evening, I created a ticket system and I create these tickets with a reaction. It works but I want to remove the reaction at the end of the event.

I will be done if the event was "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD", but I use the raw event.
I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
bot.on('raw', event => {
    if(event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") {
        if(event.d.emoji.name === "") {
            var user = bot.guilds.get(event.d.guild_id).members.get(event.d.user_id);
            if(user.user.id === botconfig.botID) return;
            var channel = bot.channels.get(event.d.channel_id);
            var message = channel.messages.fetch(event.d.message_id).then(msg => {
                ticket.createTicket(bot, msg, msg.content.split(" ").slice(1), user)
                // event.d.emoji.remove(user)
            })
    }
}
});
```

Sincerely

Comment: I'm really stupid, the solution is: 
`msg.reactions.get("").users.remove(user);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You beat us to it...

> [T]he solution is: `msg.reactions.get("").users.remove(user);`

Using the stable branch, this code would translate to:

```js
msg.reactions.get("").remove(user);
```